# CSS for a checked radio button's label

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have a CSS accordion and I'm trying to change the `background-color` of the active label. I tried using this but couldn't get it to work. Is there something I'm missing?

```css
ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

---

HTML:

```html
<ul class="accordion">
<li>
    <label for="q-1">Content 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="q-1" checked="checked">
    <div class='content'>
        <p>Content 1 blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <label for="q-2">Content 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="q-2">
    <div class='content'>
        <p>Content 2 blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

And here is my CSS:

```css
/* Clean up the lists styles */
    ul.accordion {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Hide the radio buttons */
/* These are what allow us to toggle content panes */
ul.accordion label + input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
}

/* Give each content pane some styles */
ul.accordion li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}

ul.accordion ul {
    margin-top: -15px;
}

/* Make the main tab look more clickable */
ul.accordion label {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: -5px -10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

/* Set up the div that will show and hide */
ul.accordion div.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 10px;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the content boxes when the radio buttons are checked */
ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked + div.content {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hvhL5ouk/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no previous selector in CSS, you will have to move the `input` element before `label` and use the adjacent sibling(`+`) selector to select the `label` when `input` is `:checked`.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #000;
}
```

---

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvhL5ouk/4/)**

```css
/* Clean up the lists styles */

ul.accordion {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Hide the radio buttons */

/* These are what allow us to toggle content panes */

ul.accordion input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}
/* Give each content pane some styles */

ul.accordion li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
/* Make the main tab look more clickable */

ul.accordion label {
  background-color: #666666;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
/* Set up the div that will show and hide */

ul.accordion div.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: none;
}
/* Show the content boxes when the radio buttons are checked */

ul.accordion input[type='radio']:checked + label + div.content {
  display: block;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #000;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="q-1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="q-1">Content 1</label>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>Content 1 blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="q-2" />
    <label for="q-2">Content 2</label>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>Content 2 blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fact that the `:checked` selector isn't working (that's perfectly fine), your CSS is not doing what you think it is:

```
ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked
```

That's **not selecting the `label`**. It's selecting the checked radio button that is the immediate sibling of the label (immediately after). You actually need the reverse of this, but this isn't actually possible in CSS (without editing your markup).

You'll have to switch around your `label` and `input` in your HTML, then your CSS will work:

```
<input type="radio" name="a" id="q-1" checked="checked">
<label for="q-1">Content 1</label>
```

If you want to keep the label to the left hand side of the radio button, then simply add `float: left` to the label style.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.accordion label + input[type='radio']:checked {
   background-color: #000;
}
```

This code literally mean

> find me all input radio that are checked and follow ul.accordion
>   label then set it backgound-color to #000

You would have to reverse this process to get what you want. It is not possible in CSS at the moment.

The only ways around that comes to my mind is reorder your DOM structure, using JS or pseudo-class `:before` with `z-index` that would create layer on active tab.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible with just only CSS.
By using the property `display:flex + order` to swap the `label` position to get the results you desire.

Example: https://codepen.io/tronghiep92/pen/BdrobR

Go back to your HTML markup.

```
  <li>
   <label for="q-1">Content 1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="a" id="q-1" checked="checked">
   <div class='content'>
    <p>Content 1 blah blah blah blah</p>
   </div>
 </li>
```

change to:

```
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="a" id="q-1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="q-1">Content 1</label>
    <div class='content'>
      <p>Content 1 blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
  </li>
```

and fix order/position with CSS:

```
li {
   display: flex;
}
label {
   order: 0;
}
input{
  order: 1;
}
div.content {
  order: 2;
}
input:checked ~ * {
  /* anything here you want with label and div.content*/
}
```

Some more tips: I always using tag `<label>` wrap `<input />` because click `<label>` then `<input />` is `focus, checked`.
Like in the [example](https://codepen.io/tronghiep92/pen/BdrobR) above click Icon search then `input` focus.